# Eventlet is_monkey_patched issues False

Tags: django, python-3.x, gunicorn, monkeypatching, eventlet

Hello I have a django app. My whole system configuration is the following: python 3, django 1.11, eventlet 0.21.0.

1) Nginx as an upstream server:

```
upstream proj_server {
        server unix:///tmp/proj1.sock fail_timeout=0;
        server unix:///tmp/proj2.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
```

2) Supervisor that controls workers. There is a gunicorn worker:

```
[program:proj]
command=/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/proj/bin/gunicorn -c /vagrant/proj/proj/proj/deploy/gunicorn.small.conf.py proj.wsgi:application
directory=/vagrant/proj/proj/proj/deploy
user=www-data
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/proj.log
```

3) This is a **gunicorn.small.conf** content:

```
bind = ["unix:///tmp/proj1.sock", "unix:///tmp/proj2.sock"]
pythonpath = "/vagrant/proj/proj/proj/deploy"
workers = 2
worker_class = "eventlet"
worker_connections = 10
timeout = 60
graceful_timeout = 60
```

4) And this is **proj.wsgi** content:

```
"""
WSGI config for proj project.

This module contains the WSGI application used by Django's development server
and any production WSGI deployments. It should expose a module-level variable
named ``application``. Django's ``runserver`` and ``runfcgi`` commands discover
this application via the ``WSGI_APPLICATION`` setting.

Usually you will have the standard Django WSGI application here, but it also
might make sense to replace the whole Django WSGI application with a custom one
that later delegates to the Django one. For example, you could introduce WSGI
middleware here, or combine a Django application with an application of another
framework.

"""
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()
from eventlet import wsgi
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "proj.settings")

# This application object is used by any WSGI server configured to use this
# file. This includes Django's development server, if the WSGI_APPLICATION
# setting points here.
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()

# Apply WSGI middleware here.
# from helloworld.wsgi import HelloWorldApplication
# application = HelloWorldApplication(application)
```

So, as you can see there is a chain: nginx as an upstream server calls one of the gunicorn eventlet workers using two sockets **proj1.sock** or **proj2.sock**.
Note that according with the eventlet documentation I try to use **eventlet.monkey_patch()** as early as possible. The most appropriate place for that is **proj.wsgi** that is called by gunicorn in the first place.

However it seems that library isn't monkey patched.

To check this I added to the **proj/proj/proj/__init__.py** (the first module that called by the django application) the following code:

```
import eventlet
import os
print("monkey patched os is: " + str(eventlet.patcher.is_monkey_patched('os')))
print("monkey patched select is: " + str(eventlet.patcher.is_monkey_patched('select')))
print("monkey patched socket is: " + str(eventlet.patcher.is_monkey_patched('socket')))
print("monkey patched time is: " + str(eventlet.patcher.is_monkey_patched('time')))
print("monkey patched subprocess is: " + str(eventlet.patcher.is_monkey_patched('subprocess')))

then i issued **./manage.py check** and got that answer:

monkey patched os is: false
monkey patched select is: false
monkey patched socket is: false
monkey patched time is: false
monkey patched subprocess is: false
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you change proj.wsgi file content to one line `raise Exception`? That should eliminate eventlet from suspects.

I'm not good with Django, here's a pure speculation:

- based on name, proj.wsgi is executed when WSGI server is about to start
- `manage.py check` doesn't seem to be related to remote network service (WSGI), seems to be a general management command, so it shouldn't execute WSGI related code

One possible solution, taken from your question text:

> proj/proj/proj/**init**.py (the first module that called by the django application

Try to put monkey_patch call in there.

P.S.: you don't need supervisor for gunicorn, its master process (arbiter) is designed to run forever in spite of problems with workers.

Comment: I use supervisor because there are many processes on server should be managed, not only gunicorn.
What abou wsgi - makes sense. I will try your advice, thanks.